# how to predict the IO count of mysql query?

Tags: innodb, b-tree

As InnoDB organizes its data in B+ trees. The height of the tree affects the count of IO times which may be one of the main reasons that DB slows down.

So my question is how to predicate or calculate the height of the B+ tree (e.g. based on the count of pages which can be calculated by row size, page size, and row number), and thus to make a decision whether or not to partition the data to different masters.

Comment: I gave a long answer; perhaps you would like to provide a sample query and we can discuss it in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simpler computation**

The quick and dirty answer is log base 100, rounded up.  That is, each node in the BTree has about 100 leaf nodes.  In some circles, this is called fanout.

1K rows: 2 levels
1M rows: 3 levels
billion: 5 levels
trillion: 6 levels

These numbers work for "average" rows or indexes.  Of course, you could have extremes of about 2 or 1000 for the fanout.

**Exact depth**

You can find the actual depth from some information_schema:

For Oracle's MySQL:

```
$where = "WHERE ( ( database_name = ? AND table_name = ? )
          OR      ( database_name = LOWER(?) AND table_name = LOWER(?) )  )";
$sql = "SELECT  last_update,
                n_rows,
                'Data & PK' AS 'Type',
                clustered_index_size * 16384 AS Bytes,
                ROUND(clustered_index_size * 16384 / n_rows) AS 'Bytes/row',
                clustered_index_size AS Pages,
                ROUND(n_rows / clustered_index_size) AS 'Rows/page'
        FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats
        $where
    UNION
        SELECT  last_update,
                n_rows,
                'Secondary Indexes' AS 'BTrees',
                sum_of_other_index_sizes * 16384 AS Bytes,
                ROUND(sum_of_other_index_sizes * 16384 / n_rows) AS 'Bytes/row',
                sum_of_other_index_sizes AS Pages,
                ROUND(n_rows / sum_of_other_index_sizes) AS 'Rows/page'
        FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats
        $where
          AND sum_of_other_index_sizes > 0
    ";
```

For Percona:

```
/* to enable stats:
    percona < 5.5: set global userstat_running = 1;
              5.5: set global userstat = 1; */
$sql = "SELECT  i.INDEX_NAME as Index_Name,
                IF(ROWS_READ IS NULL, 'Unused',
                    IF(ROWS_READ > 2e9, 'Overflow', ROWS_READ)) as Rows_Read
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME
                    FROM information_schema.STATISTICS
                 ) i
            LEFT JOIN information_schema.INDEX_STATISTICS s
                     ON i.TABLE_SCHEMA = s.TABLE_SCHEMA
                    AND i.TABLE_NAME = s.TABLE_NAME
                    AND i.INDEX_NAME = s.INDEX_NAME
            WHERE i.TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
              AND i.TABLE_NAME = ?
            ORDER BY IF(i.INDEX_NAME = 'PRIMARY', 0, 1), i.INDEX_NAME";
```

(Those give more than just the depth.)

`PRIMARY` refers to the data's BTree.  Names like "n_diff_pfx03" refers to the 3rd level of the BTree; the largest such number for a table indicates the total depth.

**Row width**

As for estimating the width of a row, see Bill's answer.  Here's another approach:

1. Look up the size of each column (INT=4 bytes, use averages for VARs)
2. Sum those.
3. Multiply by between 2 and 3 (to allow for overhead of InnoDB)
4. Divide into 16K to get average number of *leaf* nodes.

Non-leaf nodes, plus index leaf nodes, are trickier because you need to understand exactly what represents a "row" in such nodes.

(Hence, my simplistic "100 rows per node".)

**But who cares?**

Here's another simplification that seems to work quite well.  Since disk hits are the biggest performance item in queries, you need to  "count the disk hits" as the first order of judging the performance of a query.

But look at the caching of blocks in the buffer_pool.  A parent node is 100 times as likely to be recently touched as the child node.

So, the simplification is to "assume" that all non-leaf nodes are cached and all leaf nodes need to be fetched from disk.  Hence the *depth* is not nearly as important as how many leaf node blocks are touched.  This shoots down your "35% speedup" -- Sure 35% speedup for *CPU*, but virtually no speedup for *I/O*.  And I/O is the important component.

Note that if you fetching the latest 20 rows of a table that is chronologically stored, they will be found in the last 1 (or maybe 2) blocks.  If they are stored by a UUID, it is more likely to tale 20 blocks -- many more disk hits, hence much slower.

**Secondary Indexes**

The `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered with the data.  That implies that a look by the PK needs to drill down one BTree.  But a secondary index is implemented by a second BTree -- drill down it to find the PK, then drill down via the PK.  When "counting the disk hits", you need to consider both BTrees.  And consider the randomness (eg, for UUIDs) or not (date-ordered).

**Writes**

1. Find the block (possibly cached)
2. Update it
3. If necessary, deal with a block split
4. Flag the block as "dirty" in the buffer_pool
5. *Eventually* write it back to disk.

Step 1 *may* involve a read I/O; step 5 may involve a write I/O -- but you are not waiting for it to finish.

**Index updates**

`UNIQUE` indexes must be checked before finishing an `INSERT`.  This involves a potentially-cached read I/O.

For a non-unique index, an entry in the "Change buffer" is made.  (This lives in the buffer_pool.)  Eventually that is merged with the appropriate block on disk.  That is, no waiting for I/O when `INSERTing` a row (at least not waiting to update non-unique indexes).

Corollary:  `UNIQUE` indexes are more costly.  But is there really any need for more than 2 such indexes (including the PK)?

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the long answer. And I think your explanation is quite clear. The reason I raise this question is that our team leader said: "one level increase of the B+ tree drastically affects the query performance of InnoDB, and thus should partition the data." So I wanna a detailed understanding of the reason.

Comment: @makiXIE - `PARTITIONing` _may_ lead to shrinking the BTree depth by one, but it adds another layer, namely picking which partition(s) to use.  I feel (without any proof) that picking the partition is more costly than one level of a BTree.

Comment: @makiXIE - and...  If you want to discuss `PARTITIONing`, please start another Question.  One key point is switching to/from partitioning is to re-evaluate the indexes.  Rarely should you keep the same indexes.  Here is my discussion on `PARTITIONing`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .

Comment: Oh, no I am not wanna start discussing partitioning. The confusion point is always around " why the height of B+tree drastically affects query", so I ask a question about the IO cost calculation.

Comment: @makiXIE - And I claim that "drastically" should be replaced by "slightly".  Another point:  In steady state, a production system is very likely to have all the non-leaf blocks of each BTree cached in the buffer_pool.  Hence, no I/O except maybe for the leaf node, _regardless of depth_.

Comment: I agree with you. Only if the buffer pool gets comparably small compared to the hot data, which means the disk should be queried instead of the buffer pool, will the IO be considered. If not, another layer of the tree only affects the CPU a little, becauce all index can be in the buffer?

Comment: @makiXIE - Yes, something like that.  Note that the buffer_pool caches _16KB blocks_ from the data and index BTrees.  Some people incorrectly think that an entire index might be loaded into the buffer_pool at once.  Instead, it is one block at a time, and the are evicted in roughly a least-recently-used order.

Comment: @makiXIE - And, since virtually all lookups start by drilling down from the root node, the upper nodes of a BTree tend to stay in cache, and leaf nodes tend to get bumped out.  So... non-leaf nodes tend involve only CPU effort, while leaf nodes tend to need I/O.  That's another reason for saying that the BTree depth have very little impact on overall performance.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/04/28/the_depth_of_a_b_tree/

Let N be the number of rows in the table.

Let B be the number of keys that fit in one B-tree node.

The depth of the tree is `(log N) / (log B)`.

From the blog:

> Let’s put some numbers in there. Say you have a billion rows, and you can currently fit 64 keys in a node. Then the depth of the tree is (log 109)/ log 64 ≈ 30/6 = 5. Now you rebuild the tree with keys half the size and you get log 109 / log 128 ≈ 30/7 = 4.3. Assuming the top 3 levels of the tree are in memory, then you go from 2 disk seeks on average to 1.3 disk seeks on average, for a 35% speedup.

I would also add that usually you don't have to optimize for I/O cost, because the data you use frequently should be in the InnoDB buffer pool, therefore it won't incur any I/O cost to read it. You should size your buffer pool sufficiently to make this true for most reads.

Comment: I would add IO estimation for a write query. Assuming MySQL/InnoDB write amplification (to the tablespace page, redo log, undo log, double-write buffer, binlog - did I forget something?) it will also drive decision to shard.

Comment: Yes, I assumed this was about reads because of the importance given to B-tree depth. All the B-tree writes in InnoDB can be deferred, so they don't impact query latency, right? Log writes are not B-tree writes.

Comment: @BillKarwin I guess the buffer pool is way smaller than disk size, so when the data is large enough ( when indexes are very huge) queries hit the pool is low and the query all leads to disk io?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. InnoDB must have data and index pages in the buffer pool to read them. If they're already in the buffer pool, then they can be read without incurring any I/O cost. If they're not already in the buffer pool, then they must be copied from disk into the buffer pool, then InnoDB proceeds to read them from the buffer pool. They remain in the buffer pool to serve subsequent queries, unless something else kicks them out. You should configure a buffer pool large enough to hold your frequently-read data.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have another question about (log N) / (log B). Since rows are organized in pages, and pages are the actual leaf nodes, wouldn't it be that the page counts are N? (thus the page size and row size also affect the height?

Comment: I'll defer to Martin.FarachColton who wrote the blog I linked to. My understanding is that the values in the B-tree are index values, not page IDs. But you are correct that if you increase the page size, you can fit more B-tree nodes into a given page.

Comment: @makiXIE Increasing the page size is NOT for the faint of heart - or inexperienced.  Estimate your time required and to be safe multiply by 4.  If you do not have a 'development environment' you should consider this to be expected down time.

Comment: Right, there's in fact no way to change the page size while retaining data. You'll need to export all your InnoDB tables or convert them to MyISAM, then create a new MySQL Server instance, and import the non-InnoDB data. It's bound to be a multi-step process and involve downtime.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I know, but I mean "the page size affects the count of IO" instead of "changing the page size in a DB server".

Comment: @BillKarwin But if the leaf node refers to one page, given the size of entries N, the larger the page size, the fewer leaf nodes and the shorter of the tree?

Comment: @makiXIE I have worked with sites with 700+ connections per second and they did not have any problem with 16384 page size in achieving their data delivery goals.

Comment: Yeah, I've never encountered a reason to change the page size in 20 years of using MySQL. I've consulted for dozens of companies using MySQL.

Comment: I don't understand why it comes to the years of experience of using MySQL. I am just curious about the truth about page size and tree height, and thus the IO count. If we talk about the practical terms, we neither change the page size but partition the data if the data size, TPS or QPS is too larger. @BillKarwin

Comment: @makiXIE - Yes page size will affect tree height, but only slightly.  Here are valid reasons for bigger/smaller page size:  Smaller for random access to small records (eg, UUID-accessed); bigger for bigger rows.  Unfortunately, the page size is set for the entire instance, not each table.  I agree with Bill that 16KB is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @makiXIE - If you adjust the page size, that leads to a variety of other subtle changes -- number of blocks in the same sized buffer_pool, time to perform maintenance on that number of blocks, tiny tables wasting more/less buffer_pool space, block splits being faster or slower, etc.

Comment: @makiXIE - Fetching a block from disk is, by far, the most costly step in a read -- far more costly than drilling down N layers of BTree.